# Capture start and end of lambda functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch-events

Is it possible to capture the startTime and endTime of execution of lambda functions along with parameters that were passed to it ? 
I couldn't find any state-change event configurations that could be configured to send events when lambda function starts/terminates?

A crappy alternative is to record parameters & start time in database when the lambda is being invoked and have the lambda update the endgame as final step before it's completion. This appears prone to failures scenarios like function erroring out before updating DB.

Are there other alternatives to capture this information

Comment: If you set CloudTrial trail to log Data events for lambda, you will be able to get `invoke` event in CloudWatch Events. Not terminate though.

Comment: CloudWatch Logs records the START and END of a Lambda function invocation. You can log the parameters as needed.

Comment: What are you going to do with that info? If the purpose is to just record then I agree with @jarmod above, START & END are already captured in CloudWatch, you'd just have to log the event and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

`aws x-ray` may be a good solution here. It is easy to integrate and use. You may enable it aws console.

- Go to your lambda function/ configuration tab
- Scroll down & in `AWS X-Ray` box choose `active tracing`.

Without any configuration in the code, it is going to record `start_time` and `end_time` of the function with additional meta data. You may integrate it as a library to your lambda function and send additional `subsegments` such as request parameters. Please check here for [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-sdk-nodejs-subsegments.html)

Here is a sample payload;

```
{
  "trace_id"   : "1-5759e988-bd862e3fe1be46a994272793",
  "id"         : "defdfd9912dc5a56",
  "start_time" : 1461096053.37518,
  "end_time"   : 1461096053.4042,
  "name"       : "www.example.com",
  "http"       : {
    "request"  : {
      "url"        : "https://www.example.com/health",
      "method"     : "GET",
      "user_agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/601.7.7",
      "client_ip"  : "11.0.3.111"
    },
    "response" : {
      "status"         : 200,
      "content_length" : 86
    }
  },
  "subsegments" : [
    {
      "id"         : "53995c3f42cd8ad8",
      "name"       : "api.example.com",
      "start_time" : 1461096053.37769,
      "end_time"   : 1461096053.40379,
      "namespace"  : "remote",
      "http"       : {
        "request"  : {
          "url"    : "https://api.example.com/health",
          "method" : "POST",
          "traced" : true
        },
        "response" : {
          "status"         : 200,
          "content_length" : 861
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: @learningMyWayThru by default no - you need include x-ray library, define your parameters and send it manually. it will be shown in the subsegments.